# excel function INDIRECT()

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-indirect

I have this excel function `INDIRECT($D$2&"!A:A")` which returns me a real number.

What I don't get is the "!A:A". $D$2& refers to worksheet name, so what kind of mathematical formula does it do to the column A of this worksheet ?

Answer (score 2):

The formula `A:A` returns the value in column A that's on the same row as the formula. So, if your formula is in **B6**, then `INDIRECT($D$2&"!A:A")` will return **A6** from the sheet referenced in **D2**