# MS Excel - how to use transitive reference?

Tags: excel

```
Test Number | Total Tests
Test1       | =SUM(COUNTIFS(Test1!A:A,"TestHelloWorld"))
Test2       | =SUM(COUNTIFS(Test2!A:A,"TestHelloWorld"))
Test3       | =SUM(COUNTIFS(Test3!A:A,"TestHelloWorld"))
```

How to make Excel set the `Test1!A:A` etc in the formula according to the value in `Test Number`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [excel function INDIRECT()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18584417/excel-function-indirect)

Comment: Note that `SUM` is superfluous here too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I assume correctly that test1, test2... are your sheets name. Then you can use `INDIRECT()` :

`=SUM(COUNTIFS(INDIRECT(A4&"!A:A"),">0"))`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate text to make it look like a worksheet range reference but it remains a string. Use INDIRECT to convert that string to a usable range reference.

```
Test Number | Total Tests
Test1       | =COUNTIFS(INDIRECT("'" & A2 & "'!A:A"), "TestHelloWorld")
Test2       | =COUNTIFS(INDIRECT("'" & A3 & "'!A:A"), "TestHelloWorld")
Test3       | =COUNTIFS(INDIRECT("'" & A4 & "'!A:A"), "TestHelloWorld")
              'total of all three worksheets (array formula)
              =SUM(COUNTIFS(INDIRECT("'" & A2:A4 & "'!A:A"), "TestHelloWorld"))
```

The last formula that totals all three worksheets is an array formula. You need to enter it with Ctrl+Shift+Enter, not just Enter.

Comment: @BigBen - The last is an array formula. I should have mentioned that. Thanks!